# For any function $f(xy) = f(x) f(y)$

Tags: analysis, functions

I'm stuck on a homework question and would really appreciate any help.

I have to prove or find a counterexample on the following statement:

For any function $f(xy) = f(x)*f(y)$.

I'd say this isn't true because $f(x+y) = f(x)*f(y)$,
But I'm not totally sure...

Comment: Well, $f(x)=2$ doesn't satisfy either of your equations.

Comment: try $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: You should also think about for what functions that relation does hold!

Comment: Why do you think that $f(x+y) = f(x)*f(y)$ is true for all functions?